# How do you trigger a script from inside an if statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I want to run some sql scripts if a specific schema exists. This is my attempt:

```sql
do $$
begin
  if exists (select 1 from information_schema.schemata where schema_name = 'public')
  then
    \ir ./script.sql
  end if;
end
$$;
```

But I get this error:

```
$ psql my_database -f test.sql 
psql:test.sql:8: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 5:     \ir ./script.sql
```

The same script without the `if` statement works and is able to trigger `./script.sql`.

Adding the code from `script.sql` directly in the `if` statement also works, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the `if` syntax.

How can you conditionally trigger SQL scripts?

Comment: You cannot use [`psql` meta command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) syntax inside a PL/PGSQL script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that in PL/pgSQL.

You could write a function in PL/PerlU or PL/Python that does that, or you can install the PL/sh language.